# How can i prevent from link to send me to the top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to prevent `<a href="#id">link</a>` from scrolling the page to `(0,0)`.

I have to use the "`#`" (I have to stay in the same page).

What is the proper way to prevent the page from scrolling (jQuery/JavaScript/HTML/CSS)?

*Note:
(Scrolling to the top only happens when I am on the **iPad**; I am using jQuery mobile 1.3.2).*

Comment: what is the link doing then? if you're handling the click event in jquery/javascript then call `e.preventDefault()` or `return false;` from the handler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have various ways of getting this through Javascript (which is the easiest way).

Here is an example **using JQuery**:

```
$('#myLink').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

Here is an example **using pure Javascript in the HTML**:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);'>click here</a>
```

To make it scroll to the top on your iPad, you should first determine whether the browser is a desktop application or a mobile application, and make this a conditional href on the link, executing the behaviour only when on the iPad browser, which can be much more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Just `return false` in the click handler which will prevent the browser to redirect to the link. Other way to do is by calling `preventDefault()`  method on the `event` object.

```
$('#myLink').click(function(e) {  

//Do what you want to do here

return false; 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't scroll to `(0,0)`, it scrolls to the element with the id `id`

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HnC3L/ for an example

Answer (score 0):

To prevent all empty links like `<a href="#">Link</a>` on page add this.

```
$(function() {
  $( 'a[href$="#"]' ).each(function() {
    $( this ).attr( 'href','javascript:void(0);' )
  });
});
```